# Power Loss after StreamWriter.Close() produces blank file, why?

Tags: c#, streamwriter

Ok, so to explain; I am developing for a system that can suffer a power failure at any point in time, one point that I am testing is directly after I have written a file out using a StreamWriter. The code below:

```
// Write the updated file back out to the Shell directory.
using (StreamWriter shellConfigWriter =
        new StreamWriter(@"D:\xxx\Shell\Config\Game.cfg.bak"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < configContents.Count; i++)
    {
        shellConfigWriter.WriteLine(configContents[i]);
    }
    shellConfigWriter.Close();
}

FileInfo gameCfgBackup = new FileInfo(@"D:\xxx\Shell\Config\Game.cfg.bak");
gameCfgBackup.CopyTo(@"D:\xxx\Shell\Config\Game.cfg", true);
```

Writes the contents of `shellConfigWriter` (a `List` of strings) out to a file used as a temporary store, then it is copied over the original. Now after this code has finished executing the power is lost, upon starting back up again the file `Game.cfg` exists and is the correct size, but is completely blank. At first I thought that this was due to Write-Caching being enabled on the hard drive, but even with it off it still occurs (albeit less often).

Any ideas would be very welcome!

**Update:** Ok, so after removing the `.Close()` statements and calling `.Flush()` after every write operation the files still end up blank. I could go one step further and create a backup of the original file first, before creating the new one, and then I have enough backups to do a integrity check, but I don't think it'll help to solve the underlying issue (that when I tell it to write to, flush and close a file... It doesn't!).

Comment: Is `Game.cfg.bak` blank as well?

Comment: C# has a buffer, the OS has a buffer or two and your physical disk has a buffer. I think you can only influence the first two from C#. You'll always lose some data in a power-loss situation, the question is how much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Keep the OS from buffering the output using the `FileOptions` parameter of the `FileStream` object's constructor:

```
    using (Stream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\xxx\Shell\Config\Game.cfg.bak", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 0x1000, FileOptions.WriteThrough))
    using (StreamWriter shellConfigWriter = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < configContents.Count; i++)
        {
            shellConfigWriter.WriteLine(configContents[i]);
        }
        shellConfigWriter.Flush();
        shellConfigWriter.BaseStream.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: An alternative to "new FileStream" is the static File.Create method: "File.Create(@"D:\xxx\Shell\Config\Game.cfg.bak", 0x1000, FileOptions.WriteThrough, null)".  It has a few less parameters and might look cleaner in the code.

Comment: This is work great when I test to write text file then unplug immediately. File are saved successful.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you don't have to call `shellConfigWriter.Close()` there.  The `using` statement will take care of it.  What you might want to do instead to guard against power failure is call `shellConfigWriter.Flush()`.

---

**Update**
Something else you might want to consider is that if a power failure can really happen at *any* time, it could happen in the middle of a write, such that only some of the bytes make it to a file.  There's really no way to stop that.

To protect against these scenarios, a common procedure is to use state/condition flag files.  You use the existence or non-existence on the file system of a zero-byte file with a particular name to tell your program where to pick up again when it resumes.  Then you don't create or destroy the files that trigger a particular state until you are *sure* you've reached that state and completed the previous.

The downside here is that it might mean throwing a lot of work away now and then.  But the benefit is that it means the functional part of your code looks like normal: there's very little extra work to do to make the system sufficiently robust.

Comment: Agreed, I didn't have the .Close() method in there originally for that exact reason, but I was running out of things to try! I'll try flushing after every write call, see what happens then.

Comment: No luck, still didn't write a single line.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set `AutoFlush = true;`

Comment: Yeh I could, but for the purpose of this example code it's 1 line either way; flush every for iteration or set AutoFlush to true. It still produces the same result, which is that it still produces a blank file.

Comment: Are you sure you are not just writing blank lines to the file?  ;p